# How to apply changes on dconf without restart

Tags: gnome, dbus, dconf, gsettings

Have a installer script with root permissions, for made changes to `dconf` use the `gsettings` to set all values, by example:

```
root@pc:/# DEFAULT_USER=$(id -nu 1000);
root@pc:/# apt -y install dbus-x11;
root@pc:/# sudo -u $DEFAULT_USER gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true;
```

The value is set, i check this getting value from other bash instance with non root permissions:

```
user@pc:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date;
true
```

But can not see the changes in gnome, need restart or close session for see changes.

How to apply changes from the root session (installer script) without restart the user session?, when run `gsetting set` the changes made in real time, but when call from `dbus-x11` does not apply to interface.

I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.